# Nested classes with forward declaration cause an error in clang++, but pass without warning on g++

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, inner-classes, clang++

I am trying to combine nested classes and forward declarations to keep the code legible even though it has a terribly complicated class structure. The forward declarations allow me to reduce the level of indentation here.

The following code compiles just fine on both g++-9.3 and clang++-10:

```
class A {
    public:
        class B;
};
class A::B {
    public:
        int foo=0;
};
```

However, when I'm doing the same nested within another class, this construct works without any warnings on g++, but fails on clang++:

```
class Outer {
   public:
      class A {
         public:
            class B;
      };
      class A::B {
         public:
            int foo=0;
      };
};
```

The failure for clang++ is:

```
test.cpp:7:16: error: non-friend class member 'B' cannot have a qualified name
      class A::B {
            ~~~^
1 error generated.
```

I guess this is in some way invalid code that gcc is benevolent enough to interpret correctly? I realize I could just move the class definition directly within class A, but let's say I want to keep this version with forward declarations.

Comment: Actually, clang seems to be the only one which has a problem with this: [Test on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7cx8Kd) Without deeper knowledge, I'm not that convinced whether this is against the standard but rather a fault of clang.

Answer (score 5):

#### A *class-specifier* whose *class-head-name* contains a *nested-name-specifier* may not be appear within a class; only within the enclosing namespace

From [[class]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#11):

> If a *class-head-name* **contains a *nested-name-specifier***, the *class-specifier* **shall refer to a class that was previously declared directly in the class** or namespace **to which the *nested-name-specifier* refers**, or in an element of the inline namespace set of that namespace (i.e., not merely inherited or introduced by a *using-declaration*), **and the *class-specifier* shall appear in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration.** In such cases, the *nested-name-specifier* of the *class-head-name* of the definition shall not begin with a *decltype-specifier*.

In your failing example, `A::` is the *nested-name-specifier* and `A::B { ... }` is the *class-specifier*. The criteria

> [...] the *class-specifier* shall appear **in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration.**

is not fulfilled. Particularly, note that the *class-specifier* contains  the *class-head*, which in turns contains a *class-head-name*, which in turn contains, optionally, a *nested-name-specifier*, as well as (non-optionally) a *class-name*. If the *nested-name-specifier* is present, [class]/11 applies, in which case (as emphasized above) the requirement of where the *class-specifier* is allowed applies; particularly, not being allowed nested within a class.

Thus your program is ill-formed; Clang is right.

---

We may note that Clang accepts the program if the *class-specifier* for `B` appears at namespace scope (enclosing the previous in-class declaration):

```
class Outer {
 public:
    class A {
      public:
        class B;
    };
};

class Outer::A::B {
  public:
    int foo=0;
};
```

---

Finally, note that [[class.nest]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.nest#3) mentions defining nested class in-class of the class in which they were declared, as well as at namespace scope of the enclosing namespace:

> If class `X` is defined in a namespace scope, a nested class `Y` may
> be declared in class `X` and later defined in the definition of class
> `X` or be later defined in a namespace scope enclosing the definition
> of class `X`. [_ Example:_
>
> ```
>  class E {   class I1;       // forward declaration of nested class  
>  class I2;   class I1 { };   // definition of nested class }; class
>  E::I2 { };  // definition of nested class
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]

which allows your first example:

> ```
> class A {
>   public:
>     class B;
> };
> class A::B {
>   public:
>     int foo=0;
> };
> ```

to be re-factored as

```
class A {
  public:
    class B {
      public:
        int foo=0;
    };
};
```

or

```
class A {
  public:
    class B;  // forward declaration
    // ...
    class B {
      public:
        int foo=0;
    };
};
```

but there is no conflict here with [class]/11, which specifically governs the allowed grammar for when a *class-head-name* contains a *nested-name-specifier*.

Comment: The valid constructs listed in the quote are disjunctive. Yes, the second one doesn't qualify, but it seems the first one "shall refer to a class that was previously declared directly in the class" does. I'm not sure though, I'm finding it difficult to keep track of *class-head-name*, *class-specifier*, and *class-key* :p

Comment: @cigien Yeah I agree [class]/11 is a handful, but the relevant part (in this context) is quite clear: "If a _class-head-name_ contains a _nested-name-specifier_, [...] **the _class-specifier_ shall appear** in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration.".

Comment: @cigien Note that the _class-specifier_ contains  the _class-head_, which in turns contains a _class-head-name_, which in turn contains, optionally, a _nested-name-specifier_, as well as (non-optionally) a _class-name_. If the _nested-name-specifier_ is present, [class]/11 applies, in which case the requirement of where the _class-specifier_ is allowed applies (particularly, not allowed nested within a class).

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to parse what that section is saying, it's tricky. btw, I think we might be grouping the clauses in [class]/11 differently. I feel like the "and the class-specifier shall appear in a namespace ..." applies only to the second part of "...refers, or in an element".

Comment: @cigien It's quite a horribly long (and difficult due to sequence AND:s and OR:s) sentence, but if you write it out without all the details, it becomes easier to grasp: "If PREDICATE, A shall B, or C, and A shall D.", which makes it clear that the "or C" clause relates to OR:ing on the first clause (_A shall B_), meaning that the whole paragraph could be re-written as "If PREDICATE {(A shall B) OR A shall C)} AND {A shall D}"; i.e., _A shall D_ always applies.

Comment: Yeah, I see we're grouping the predicates differently. I'm not at all convinced you're wrong, but I'm not convinced you're right either :p

Answer (score 2):

I think the code is valid, and this is a clang bug. According to [class.qual#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.qual#1):

> If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the name specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up in the scope of the class ([class.member.lookup]), **except for the cases listed below**. The name shall represent one or more members of that class or of one of its base classes ([class.derived]).
>
> ...
>
> The exceptions to the name lookup rule above are the following:
>
> > (1.1) the lookup for a destructor is as specified in [basic.lookup.qual];
> >
> > (1.2) a conversion-type-id of a conversion-function-id is looked up in the same manner as a conversion-type-id in a class member access (see [basic.lookup.classref]);
> >
> > (1.3) the names in a template-argument of a template-id are looked up in the context in which the entire postfix-expression occurs;
> >
> > (1.4) the lookup for a name specified in a using-declaration ([namespace.udecl]) also finds class or enumeration names hidden within the same scope.

None of the exceptions apply to the case of `A::B`. There is no destructor being named, no conversion-type-id, no templates, and no using declaration.

`A` is in scope, and `B` is an accessible member of `A`, so the lookup should succeed.

Comment: [class.qual] is specifically about lookup, not grammar. [class], on the other hand, governs the grammar for classes.

Comment: @dfrib Hmm, that much is true. I'm not sure the class grammar disallows this though. I'll ask on your answer.