# Simple forward declaration compiles with g++ but not clang

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++, clang++, forward-declaration

As for a minimally reproducible example, say I have the following class `A` defined in a header file `a.h`:

```
// file a.h
#include <cstdio>

class A {
private:
    int val;
public:
    A(int aVal) { val = aVal; }
    int getVal() { return val; }
};
```

And also I have a class `Container` defined via a `container.h` header and a `container.cpp` source

Header:

```
// file container.h
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

class A;

class Container {
private:
    unsigned int size = 0;
    A *data = nullptr;
public:
    Container();
    Container(int size);
    ~Container();

    A getElement(unsigned int pos); 

    template <typename... Args>
    void emplace(unsigned int pos, const Args & ...args);
};

template <typename... Args>
void Container::emplace(unsigned int pos, const Args & ...args)
{
    new(data + pos) A(args...);
}
```

Source:

```
// file container.cpp
#include "container.h"
#include "a.h"

Container::Container() {}

Container::Container(int size)
{
    data = static_cast<A*>(malloc(sizeof(A) * size));
}

Container::~Container()
{
    free(data);
    data = nullptr;
}

A Container::getElement(unsigned int pos)
{
    return data[pos];
}
```

For testing, I use the following `main.cpp`:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "container.h"


int main()
{
    A a(11);
    Container c(1);
    c.emplace(0, a);
    printf("%i\n", c.getElement(0).getVal()); // should print '11' to the console
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile and run the code, all works well with g++ (tested with versions 8 through 12). But clang throws the errors:

```
In file included from container.cpp:1:
./container.h:27:11: error: arithmetic on a pointer to an incomplete type 'A'
new(data + pos) A(args...);
            ~~~~ ^
./container.h:7:7: note: forward declaration of 'A'
class A;
      ^
./container.h:27:18: error: allocation of incomplete type 'A'
new(data + pos) A(args...);
                        ^
./container.h:7:7: note: forward declaration of 'A'
class A;
      ^
2 errors generated.
```

What could be going on? Is this a perhaps a clang bug? The code not only compiles, but works perfectly with g++ both in this minimal version I included here and in the much more complicated version from my real code. So it is not a mere "g++ is compiling broken stuff without warning".

Note that **I did find** a couple of previous questions that touch on analogous **but different** issues. For example, the question [Nested classes with forward declaration cause an error in clang++, but pass without warning on g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64895983/nested-classes-with-forward-declaration-cause-an-error-in-clang-but-pass-with) seems to also find problems with forward declaration with clang but the discussion there is specific about nested classes and namespaces. Another example is the question [Confusion (or Clang bug?) about incomplete types in std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75257501/confusion-or-clang-bug-about-incomplete-types-in-stdvector), also with clang giving weird behavior in the presence of forward declaration. But there the issue was related to subtle differences in specifying/not-specifying default constructors. A third example is the question [Code compiles with g++ but not clang++ if incomplete type is used in templated function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70357084/code-compiles-with-g-but-not-clang-if-incomplete-type-is-used-in-templated-f), but that relates to a ill-formed template, i.e. the problem of "a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template parameter".

Hence, the problem I bring here may be **related** to those, but it is more generic and stripped down to the basics - illustrating a more pervasive problem with forward declaration that shows up only with clang.

Therefore my question: is there a way to alter my code above (of course, still using forward declaration of class `A` in `container.h` instead of including `a.h` within `container.h`) that will satisfy clang and g++ alike?

Comment: `A(args...)` is a type-dependent expression, so it'll see the full definition of `class A` that comes later.  `(data + pos)` is not dependent on any template parameter, so names will be looked up in the first phase... but it's not the name lookup at issue here.

Comment: @DaveS what do you mean? templated functions must be in header files.

Comment: @BenVoigt about `(data + pos)`: exactly, I can't see why that is giving clang any issues. I did think the same as you about `A(args...)` but I am still puzzled by rather old g++ versions handling it while recent clang does not. This makes critical difference, since by not handling that as g++, clang is forcing a lot of expensive header inclusions all around my code - resulting in a critical compilation time cost when compared to g++.

Comment: @River - my bad you're correct. One discussion here of hack-arounds - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-6.5 does seem to apply, so your code is IFNDR.  https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-6.7 is relevant

Comment: @BenVoigt That looks to be it, nice find.  I was trying to find the same thing.

Comment: @BenVoigt wow, thanks. It is kind of wild that g++ **seems** to be able to consistently handle this particular case regardless of being IFNDR (on a few large complex code bases I have been using it at / testing it with). The compilation performance difference that this type of forward declaration can enable is huge. I am very surprised that this IFNDR and the differences between how g++ and clang area dealing with it are not much more widely well-known / debated online.

Comment: Clang follows the standard much more strictly than gcc and msvc where it comes to declaration order of templates, it's not too uncommon to find code that only clang rejects